# Google Analytics Search and Replace filter including request URI parts that have been exluded

Tags: google-analytics, regular-expression

I have a search and replace filter that should "roll up" pages underneath different apps.

MY URLs have the structure `hostname/app-name/page.htm?query`

App name could be one of several options.

My intent is that if I have requests come in on both

```
example.com/dave/page.htm?query
```

and

```
example.com/susan/page.htm?query
```

That both those requests get counted as "hits" for `page.htm`

I have the following `^/(dave|susan|adam)/([^\?]+)\?.*`

and have set the replace field to be `/2`

I can see hits being rolled up for page.htm but am also seeing `dave/page.htm` and `susan/page.htm` show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The filter field is of course set to Request URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google's documentation for these filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en) doesn't mention that they can use regular expression groups for matching.  I think that when you say `/2` you are trying to fill in the second matching group.   The normal regular expression syntax for that would include either a `$` or a `\` before the number.  If it were going to work, it would either be `/$2` or `/\2`.

I don't think you need functionality at all.  You could just use the regular expression `^/(dave|susan|adam)/` on the Request URI field and replace it with `/`.   That should work because it is almost exactly like the example used on the documentation page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm no longer working on the project I needed this for so am unable to test this but this sounds like the right answer so I will give you the tick. :)